# Boolean Expression with String Comparison in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-aggregation

`$cond` in mongodb is defined like this:

```
$cond: { if: { $gte: [ "$qty", 250 ] }, then: 30, else: 20 }
```

But, can we do that for a string ? I want to compare string value inside a document with regex, so something like this can work:

```
$cond: { if: { $match: [/sam/, "$name"] }, then: 30, else: 20 }
```

`/sam/` is a regular expression and `"$name"` is the field that I want to compare to. As a side note, this expression will be put in the aggregate pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is currently not possible and is an open [feature request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11947) for quite a while.
Depending on your needs you may be able to do your stuff with [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/#exp._S_substr)

Comment: $regexmatch in that example closely match what I need. Guess I need to make use of $substr